# bad gateway 502: connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock failed in error.log

Tags: ubuntu, php, nginx

I installed php8.1 on ubuntu 18.04 but getting problems. I am getting 502 Bad Gateway error. The error.log is giving following error:

```
2022/06/30 17:48:38 [crit] 2224#2224: *1 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: _, request: "GET /w3_scalar.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock:", host: "localhost
```

Other details are:

```
$ sudo nginx -t
[sudo] password for zulfi: 
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

and

```
$ sudo systemctl restart php8.1-fpm
~$ sudo systemctl status nginx.service
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: en
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2022-06-29 15:49:48 CDT; 1 day 2h ago
     Docs: man:nginx(8)
  Process: 2220 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code
  Process: 2010 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process 
 Main PID: 2221 (nginx)
    Tasks: 13 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
           ├─2221 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_pro
           ├─2224 nginx: worker process
           ├─2226 nginx: worker process



~$ journalctl -xe
-- Unit systemd-hostnamed.service has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is RESULT.
Jun 30 17:58:08 lc2530hz audit[20050]: AVC apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="connect
Jun 30 17:58:08 lc2530hz audit[20050]: AVC apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="file_pe
Jun 30 17:58:08 lc2530hz audit[20050]: AVC apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="file_pe
Jun 30 17:58:08 lc2530hz audit[20050]: AVC apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="file_pe
Jun 30 17:58:08 lc2530hz audit[20050]: AVC apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="file_pe
Jun 30 17:58:08 lc2530hz kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1656629888.891:266): app
Jun 30 17:58:08 lc2530hz kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1656629888.891:267): app
Jun 30 17:58:08 lc2530hz kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1656629888.891:268): app
Jun 30 17:58:08 lc2530hz kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1656629888.891:269): app
Jun 30 17:58:08 lc2530hz kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1656629888.891:270): app
Jun 30 17:58:09 lc2530hz org.gnome.Nautilus[4167]: func=xmlSecCheckVersionExt:fi
Jun 30 17:58:09 lc2530hz kernel: CPU4: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clo
Jun 30 17:58:09 lc2530hz kernel: CPU10: Core temperature above threshold, cpu cl
Jun 30 17:58:09 lc2530hz kernel: CPU4: Core temperature/speed normal
Jun 30 17:58:09 lc2530hz kernel: CPU10: Core temperature/speed normal
```

Files information is:

```
/etc/php/8.1/fpm/php-fpm.conf
pid = /run/php/php8.1-fpm.pid
error_log = /var/log/php8.1-fpm.log
include=/etc/php/8.1/fpm/pool.d/*.conf

/etc/php/8.1/fpm/pool.d/www.conf:
user = www-data
group = www-data
listen = /run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock
listen.group = www-data
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
```

Some body please guide me how to solve this bad Gateway 502 error when I execute my php file on browser using : http://localhost/w3_scalar.php

Note the above file was running on php 7.4
Zulfi.

==Jul 3 2022
@Tom Yan
:First command

```
 $ systemctl status php8.1-fpm
    ● php8.1-fpm.service - The PHP 8.1 FastCGI Process Manager
       Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/php8.1-fpm.service; enabled; vendor prese
       Active: active (running) since Sun 2022-07-03 16:58:24 CDT; 42min ago
         Docs: man:php-fpm8.1(8)
      Process: 2087 ExecStartPost=/usr/lib/php/php-fpm-socket-helper install /run/ph
     Main PID: 1921 (php-fpm8.1)
       Status: "Processes active: 0, idle: 2, Requests: 0, slow: 0, Traffic: 0req/se
        Tasks: 3 (limit: 4915)
       CGroup: /system.slice/php8.1-fpm.service
               ├─1921 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php/8.1/fpm/php-fpm.conf)
               ├─2079 php-fpm: pool www
               └─2085 php-fpm: pool www
    
    Jul 03 16:58:24 lc2530hz systemd[1]: Starting The PHP 8.1 FastCGI Process Manage
    Jul 03 16:58:24 lc2530hz systemd[1]: Started The PHP 8.1 FastCGI Process Manager
```

Second Command:

```
$ journalctl -bu php8.1-fpm
Failed to parse boot descriptor 'u'
```

I found the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51158830/nginx-connect-to-unix-var-run-php7-2-fpm-sock-failed-2-no-such-file-or-dir,

but it is not related to php8.1-fpm, somebody please guide me.

```
$ sudo ps aux | grep 'php'
[sudo] password for zulfi: 
root      1921  0.0  0.1 454156 27524 ?        Ss   16:58   0:00 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php/8.1/fpm/php-fpm.conf)
www-data  2079  0.0  0.0 456452 13896 ?        S    16:58   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
www-data  2085  0.0  0.0 456452 13896 ?        S    16:58   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
zulfi    13627  0.0  0.0 210984  6284 ?        Sl   17:39   0:00 /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/oosplash --writer file:///home/zulfi/Linux_Forum_SC%20Tools/nginx/nginx%20for%20php8/502%20bad%20gateway%20connect%20problem8p1.odt
zulfi    13646 99.7  2.7 2006652 443460 ?      Rl   17:39  25:54 /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin --writer file:///home/zulfi/Linux_Forum_SC%20Tools/nginx/nginx%20for%20php8/502%20bad%20gateway%20connect%20problem8p1.odt --splash-pipe=5
zulfi    15893  0.0  0.0  14432  1116 pts/0    S+   18:05   0:00 grep --color=auto php
```

Also:
~`$ sudo systemctl is-active php8.1-fpm.service`
active

@Tom Yan

```
$ ls -l /var/
total 52
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     4096 Jul  3 17:03 backups
drwxr-xr-x 18 root root     4096 May 27 17:18 cache
drwxrwsrwt  2 root whoopsie 4096 Jun 22 16:44 crash
drwxr-xr-x 86 root root     4096 Feb 18 23:31 lib
drwxrwsr-x  2 root staff    4096 Apr 24  2018 local
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root        9 Feb  8  2019 lock -> /run/lock
drwxrwxr-x 18 root syslog   4096 Jul  3 17:03 log
drwxrwsr-x  2 root mail     4096 Jul 24  2018 mail
drwxrwsrwt  2 root whoopsie 4096 Jul 24  2018 metrics
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     4096 Jul 24  2018 opt
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root        4 Feb  8  2019 run -> /run
drwxr-xr-x 21 root root     4096 Apr 12 23:08 snap
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root     4096 Jul 24  2018 spool
drwxrwxrwt  9 root root     4096 Jul  3 18:09 tmp
drwxrwxrwx  3 root root     4096 May 23  2019 w
```

@Tom Yan

still getting: `2022/07/03 18:48:19 [crit] 2108#2108: *6 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: _, request: "GET /w3_static.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock:", host: "localhost"`

status:

```
$ sudo systemctl status /var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock
[sudo] password for zulfi: 
Unit var-run-php-php8.1\x2dfpm.sock.mount could not be found.
```

My listen=listen = /run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock, should I change it to /var/run/php8.1-fpm.sock?

@Tom Yan,stat gives me error:

```
$stat /var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock
stat: cannot stat '/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock': No such file or directory
```

I have other versions also:

```
$ ls /etc/php
7.2  8.0  8.1
```

Are they creating problem?
@Tom Yan ==July 4, 2022

```
~$ ls /var/run/
acpid.pid             initctl             snap.docker
acpid.socket          initramfs           snapd-snap.socket
alsa                  libvirt             snapd.socket
apache2               libvirtd.pid        spice-vdagentd
avahi-daemon          lock                sshd
boltd                 log                 sshd.pid
console-setup         lvm                 sudo
containerd            lvmetad.pid         systemd
crond.pid             mlocate.daily.lock  teamviewerd.ipc
crond.reboot          mount               teamviewerd.pid
cups                  mysqld              thermald
dbus                  netns               tmpfiles.d
dhclient6-wlp2s0.pid  network             udev
dhclient-wlp2s0.pid   NetworkManager      udisks2
dmeventd-client       nginx.pid           unattended-upgrades.lock
dmeventd-server       php                 user
docker                plymouth            utmp
docker.pid            pppconfig           uuidd
docker.sock           rsyslogd.pid        wpa_supplicant
ebtables.lock         sendsigs.omit.d     xtables.lock
gdm3                  shm
gdm3.pid              snapd
```

and

@lc2530hz:

```
~$ ls /var/run/php
php8.1-fpm.pid
```

@lc2530hz:~$
Also www.conf has following addition:

```
listen.user  = www-data
```

and
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
changed to:

```
listen = 127.0.0.1
```

Do I still need:

```
listen.owner = www-data
```

@Tom Yan, I am getting failed message:

```
$ sudo systemctl restart php8.1-fpm
Job for php8.1-fpm.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status php8.1-fpm.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
zulfi@lc2530hz:/etc/php/8.1/fpm/pool.d$ systemctl status php8.1-fpm.service
● php8.1-fpm.service - The PHP 8.1 FastCGI Process Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/php8.1-fpm.service; enabled; vendor prese
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2022-07-04 18:26:53 CDT; 1min 54
     Docs: man:php-fpm8.1(8)
```

and
$ journalctl -xe
Jul 04 18:28:48 lc2530hz kernel: CPU6: Package temperature above threshold, cpu
Jul 04 18:28:48 lc2530hz kernel: CPU1: Package temperature above threshold, cpu
Jul 04 18:28:48 lc2530hz kernel: CPU7: Pack

ag
==5-26-2023
@QuintenWu
I checked my configuration file here:

```
/etc/nginx$ ls
conf.d          koi-win            nginx.conf       sites-enabled
fastcgi.conf    mime.types         proxy_params     snippets
fastcgi_params  modules-available  scgi_params      uwsgi_params
koi-utf         modules-enabled    sites-available  win-utf
```

following are the contents of my configuration file for nginx:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;



    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    

    gzip on;


    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

I can't find the line:

```
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
```

Kindly tell me which file are you asking me to edit?

Zulfi.

Comment: Why aren't you showing `systemctl status php8.1-fpm` / `journalctl -bu php8.1-fpm`?

Comment: @Tom Yan
, please guide. I put the output of the commands you requested in my main thread. Somebody please guide me.

Comment: How does your `ls -l /var/` look? (It should be `-b -u php8.1-fpm` btw. My bad. But it's fine you don't need to add the output back.)

Comment: @Tom Yan, added.

Comment: Hmm. Have you checked with `stat /var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock` anyway? Also, does the same error actually show up in `error.log` with new timestamp if you access again the/a php file from the browser now?

Comment: @Tom Yan, added above, listen=listen = /run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock, should I change it to /var/run/php8.1-fpm.sock?

Comment: `stat`, not `systemctl status`. I don't know. Essentially with the symlink you should be fine (although the more ideal way is to have `../run` instead of `/run`). What I'm thinking is that there's something wrong down the path, inspite of the conf file you pasted.

Comment: @Tom Yan, my friend I am getting an error, pasted above. Zulfi.

Comment: So it's not a problem of nginx, because the `.sock` indeed does not exist. Have you checked what's inside `(/var)/run/` and, if exists, `(/var)/run/php/`? Also is there a particular reason that `listen = 127.0.0.1:9000` exists / `listen.user = www-data` is missing in `www.conf`?

Comment: @Tom Yan, Still can't beat 'bad gateway'. Maybe we are very close.

Comment: It might have something to do with the distro-specific versioning hack (including but not limited to `/usr/lib/php/php-fpm-socket-helper`). I don't think I can offer much more. Try not to have any `listen =` line other than the one with the `.sock` path.

Comment: @Tom Yan, I am now getting php8.1-fpm.service failed message, see above.

Comment: I did meant `listen.owenr` btw. And I didn't meant you can try removing just `9000`, but as I just said, remove the whole line. Btw `journalctl -xe` is practically useless. Use `journalctl -b -u UNIT_NAME` (don't just copy and paste "UNIT_NAME" here; try to understand what I mean by that).

Comment: @Tom Yan,Sorry I don't know what is unit name?

Answer (score 0):

Did you update your corresponding web server config? For example from

```
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
```

to

```
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
```

This did the trick for me.

PS: Apologies, I just stumbled on this question. A year late, but here you go.